# Overlapping multi-parameter instances and instance specificity

Tags: haskell, typeclass, overlapping-instances, multiparameter

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module OverlappingSpecificsError where

class EqM a b where
    (===) :: a -> b -> Bool

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Eq a => EqM a a where
    a === b = a == b

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} EqM a b where
    a === b = False

aretheyreallyeq :: (Eq a, Eq b) => Either a b -> Either a b -> Bool
aretheyreallyeq (Left a1) (Right b2) = a1 == b2

aretheyeq :: (Eq a, Eq b) => Either a b -> Either a b -> Bool
aretheyeq (Left a1) (Right b2) = a1 === b2
```

Neither `aretheyreallyeq` or `aretheyeq` compile, but the error for `aretheyreallyeq` makes sense to me, and also tells me that `aretheyeq` should not give an error: One of the instances that GHCi suggests are possible for `EqM` in `aretheyeq` should be impossible due to the same error on `aretheyreallyeq`. What's going on?

The point is, GHCi insists that both of the instances of `EqM` are applicable in `aretheyeq`. But `a1` is of type `a` and `b2` is of type `b`, so in order for the first instance to be applicable, it would have to have the types `a` and `b` unify.

But this should not be possible, since they are declared as type variables at the function signature (that is, using the first `EqM` instance would give rise to the function being of type `Either a a -> Either a a -> Bool`, and the error in `aretheyreallyeq` tells me that GHCi will not allow that (which is what I expected anyway).

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in how overlapping instances with multi-parameter type classes are checked?

I am thinking maybe it has to do with the fact that `a` and `b` could be further instantiated later on to the point where they are equal, outside `aretheyeq`, and then the first instance **would** be valid? But the same is true for `aretheyreallyeq`. The only difference is that if they do not ever unify we have an option for `aretheyeq`, but we do not for `aretheyreallyeq`. In any case, Haskell does not have dynamic dispatch for plenty of good and obvious reasons, so what is the fear in committing to the instance that will **always** work regardless of whether later on `a` and `b` are unifiable? Maybe there is some way to present this that would make choosing the instance when calling the function possible in some way?

It is worth noting that if I remove the second instance, then the function obviously still does not compile, stating that no instance `EqM a b` can be found. So if I do not have that instance, then none works, but when that one works, suddenly the other does too and I have an overlap? Smells like bug to me miles away.

Comment: You might want to compare types `a` and `b` for equality at _runtime_ instead of compile time. If so, you could use `Typeable a, Typeable b` as an additional constraint. Note that, if you do, you will have to satisfy the constraints at each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a bug in sense of working [exactly as documented](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overlapping-instances). Starting with

> Now suppose that, in some client module, we are searching for an instance of the target constraint `(C ty1 .. tyn)`. The search works like this:

The first stage of finding *candidate instances* works as you expect; `EqM a b` is the only candidate and so the prime candidate. But the last step is

> Now find all instances, or in-scope given constraints, that unify with the target constraint, but do not match it. Such non-candidate instances might match when the target constraint is further instantiated. If all of them are incoherent top-level instances, the search succeeds, returning the prime candidate. Otherwise the search fails.

The `EqM a a` instance falls into this category, and isn't incoherent, so the search fails. And you can achieve the behavior you want by marking it as `{-# INCOHERENT #-}` instead of overlappable.

Comment: I had read that page a million times before posting this, but I hadn't realized that last bit referred precisely to this. Thanks for pointing that out. Never quite understood what it meant by "it unifies, but it does not match it".

I don't think marking it as incoherent will work for my real application, as in that case I have two instances which are somehow symmetrical but each of them step onto the other on different situations, by finding a not matching potential instantiation as in the case I presented. I'd have to mark them both as incoherent and that would probably not work?

Comment: It'll likely end up in "If all the remaining candidates are incoherent, the search succeeds, returning an arbitrary surviving candidate" in at least some situations. Whether it's acceptable for your use-case I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Instance matching on generic variables works this way in order to prevent some potentially confusing (and dangerous) scenarios.

If the compiler gave in to your intuition and chose the `EqM a b` instance when compiling `aretheyeq` (because `a` and `b` do not necessarily unify, as you're saying), then the following call:

```
x = aretheyeq (Left 'z') (Right 'z')
```

would return `False`, contrary to intuition.

**Q**: wait a second! But in this case, `a ~ Char` and `b ~ Char`, and we also have `Eq a` and `Eq b`, which means `Eq Char`, which should make it possible to choose the `EqM a a` instance, shouldn't it?

Well, yes, I suppose this *could* be happening in theory, but Haskell just doesn't work this way. Class instances are merely extra parameters passed to functions (as method dictionaries), so in order for there to be an instance, it must either be unambiguously choosable within the function itself, *or* it must be passed in from the consumer.

The former (unambiguously choosable instance) necessarily requires that there is just one instance. And indeed, if you remove the `EqM a a` instance, your function compiles and always returns `False`.

The latter (passing an instance from the consumer) means a constraint on the function, like this:

```
aretheyeq :: EqM a b => Either a b -> Either a b -> Bool
```

What you are asking is that Haskell essentially has two different versions of this function: one requiring that `a ~ b` and picking the `EqM a a` instance, and the other not requiring that, and picking the `EqM a b` instance.

And then the compiler would cleverly pick the "right" version. So that if I call `aretheyeq (Left 'z') (Right 'z')`, the first version gets called, but if I call `aretheyeq (Left 'z') (Right 42)` - the second.

But now think further: if there are two versions of `aretheyeq`, and which one to pick depends on whether the types are equal, then consider this:

```
dummy :: a -> b -> Bool
dummy a b = aretheyeq (Left a) (Right b)
```

How does `dummy` know which version of `aretheyeq` to pick? So now there has to be two versions of `dummy` as well: one for when `a ~ b` and another for other cases.

And so on. The ripple effect continues until there are concrete types.

**Q**: wait a second! Why two versions? Can't there be just one version, which then decides what to do based on what arguments are passed in?

Ah, but it can't! This is because types are erased at compile time. By the time the function starts to run, it's already compiled, and there is no more type information. So everything has to be decided at compile time: which instance to pick, and the ripple effect from it.

Comment: I think you also did not understand my point. I really don't want the `EqM a a` instance to ever be used in `aretheyeq`. Ever. So you're basically making my point for me: there's no dynamic dispatching, no guessing. It should just choose the `EqM a b` instance and be done with it. Why is it even a problem that the `EqM a a` instance, which clearly would never work, exists?

Comment: If I had the `EqM a b` constraint on the function, that would be a whole different story. Then the function should compile, no questions asked, and then perhaps it could sometimes use the `EqM a a` instance when it is invoked with more instantiated types that make this one possible. And in such a case, the overlapping would be checked anyway at the top level where it was called. So checking this here, where I do not have this constraint on the function, serves no purpose other than make my life difficult.

Comment: "I think you also did not understand my point" - I actually answered that in the very first paragraph: if the compiler always chose `EqM a b` in these circumstances, it would lead to unexpected results like that.

Comment: I forgot about that first part after reading the rest. I cannot understand why would that be contrary to intuition. The usage of `===` is inside the function. The function type does not have an `EqM` constraint. So when using it you wouldn't even need to know that it makes use of `EqM`. When programming it, you are aware that `a` and `b` are different type variables and therefore that the `EqM a a` instance would never be used. What confusion is there to be had?

If you tried to second guess how each function you use is implemented, you'd be doomed. The function should describe what it does.

Comment: There is a difference between a formal explanation and intuitive expectation. The expectation that the "right" instance gets magically chosen is common sense enough that the compiler designers choose to reject this situation at the cost of rejecting some correct programs. This is the fundamental choice of language design. Every feature makes this trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

To further complete Alexey's answer, which really gave me the hint at what I should do to achieve the behaviour I wanted, I compiled the following minimum working example of a slightly different situation more alike my real use case (which has to do with `ExistentialQuantification`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
module ExistentialTest where

class Class1 a b where
    foo :: a -> b

instance {-# INCOHERENT #-} Monoid a => Class1 a (Either b a) where
    foo x = Right (x <> x)

instance {-# INCOHERENT #-} Monoid a => Class1 a (Either a b) where
    foo x = Left x

data Bar a = Dir a | forall b. Class1 b a => FromB b

getA :: Bar a -> a
getA (Dir a) = a
getA (FromB b) = foo b

createBar :: Bar (Either String t)
createBar = FromB "abc"

createBar2 :: Bar (Either t String)
createBar2 = FromB "def"
```

If you remove the `{-# INCOHERENT #-}` annotations, you get exactly the same compile errors as in my original example on both `createBar` and `createBar2`, and the point is the same: in `createBar` it is clear that the only suitable instance is the second one, whereas in `createBar2` the only suitable one is the first one, but Haskell refuses to compile because of this apparent confusion it might create when using it, **until you annotate them with** `INCOHERENT`.

And then, the code works exactly as you'd expect it to: `getA createBar` returns `Left "abc"` whereas `getA createBar2` returns `Right "defdef"`, which is exactly the only thing that could happen in a sensible type system.

So, my conclusion is: the `INCOHERENT` annotation is precisely to allow what I wanted to do since the beginning without Haskell complaining about potentially confusing instances and indeed taking the only one that makes sense. A doubt remains as to whether `INCOHERENT` may make it so that instances that indeed remain overlapping even after taking into account everything compile, using an arbitrary one (which is obviously bad and dangerous). So, a corollary to my conclusion is: only use `INCOHERENT` when you absolutely need to and are absolutely convinced that there is indeed only one valid instance.

I still think it is a bit absurd that Haskell has no more natural and safe way to tell the compiler to stop worrying about me being potentially being confused and doing what is obviously the only type checking answer to the problem...

Answer (score -1):

`aretheyreallyeq` fails because there are two different type variables in scope. In

```
aretheyreallyeq :: (Eq a, Eq b) => Either a b -> Either a b -> Bool
aretheyreallyeq (Left a1) (Right b2) = a1 == b2
```

`a1 :: a`, and `b2 :: b`, there's no method for comparing values of potentially different types (as this is how they're declared), so this fails. This has nothing to do with any of the enabled extensions or pragmas of course.

`aretheyeq` fails because there are two instances that *could* match, not that they definitely do. I'm not sure what version of GHC you're using but here's the exception message I see and it seems to be fairly clear to me:

```
    • Overlapping instances for EqM a b arising from a use of ‘===’
      Matching instances:
        instance [overlappable] EqM a b -- Defined at /home/tmp.hs:12:31
        instance [overlappable] Eq a => EqM a a
          -- Defined at /home/tmp.hs:9:31
      (The choice depends on the instantiation of ‘a, b’
       To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
       when compiling the other instance declarations)
    • In the expression: a1 === b2
      In an equation for ‘aretheyeq’:
          aretheyeq (Left a1) (Right b2) = a1 === b2
```

In this case, my interpretation is that it's saying that given certain choices for a and b, there are potentially multiple different matching instances.

Comment: I already know all of that. But I think you failed to understand my point. The second instance is `EqM a a`. In order for that to match given the signature of `aretheyreallyeq`, it would have to force `aretheyreallyeq` to have type variables `a` and `b` be equal. If you were able to do that, then `aretheyeq` would also type check. Which is proven, by the way, if you simply remove the other instance of `EqM`: that function still does not compile, because the instance that it claims would overlap isn't actually a valid instance.

The instance `EqM a a` could never match.